# How to mock directive on mock component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, clarity

I'm unit testing a component which contains `clarity` tags with `clarit directives`.

I have mocked out the clarity tags but they have directives `clrDgItems` which I can't mock with directive class.

```
<clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let item of items$ | async | filter : listFilter.keyword : ['trackingCode', 'title']" [clrDgItem]="episode">
```

I could replace `clrDgItems` with `ngFor` but the table filter stops working.

Without it the test does not compile :

> Can't bind to 'clrDgItemsOf' since it isn't a known property of
>   'clr-dg-row'

When I add mockDirective as: I get error

> Failed: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

```
     function MockDirective(options: any): Directive {
         const metadata: Directive = {
         selector: options.selector,
         inputs: options.inputs,
         outputs: options.outputs
      };
      return new Directive(metadata);
    }

 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        MockDirective({
          selector: '[clrDgItemsOf]',
        }),
      MockComponent({
      selector: 'clr-dg-row',
      template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
      outputs: ['clrDgItemsOf'],
      inputs: ['clrDgItem']
    }), ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any reason why you are not using the [`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA)? You don't need to mock directives then, as those are simply ignored:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule,    
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
```

If you really want to mock behaviour, you can just create a `@Directive` inside your spec file:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clrDgItems][clrDgItemsOf]'
})
export class MockClrDgItemsDirective {
  @Input()
  clrDgItemsOf: any;
}
```

and add it to your declarations like normally:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MockClrDgItemsDirective
  ]
})
```

Even another option is to just import the `ClrDatagridModule` in the imports of your `TestBed`

Comment: i get error `Property binding clrDgItemsOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("mn [clrDgField]="'title'">Title</clr-dg-column>
            <clr-dg-column>Comments</clr-dg-column>`

Comment: @shiva and what if you create the `MockClrDgItemsDirective` inside your spec?

Comment: Actually it worked! thank you. Although I perefer to mock all child components. It gives me more flexibility e.g test the inner values ...