# Angular + karma tests failing intermittently

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I recently upgraded our project's application version from 9 to 13 and as a part of it also upgraded few packages used including chromedriver, node, karma etc. Now we are using node v16 and angular v13 and karma v6.3.11.

I have karma.conf.js setup with concurrency Infinity and I see that specific unit test fail every time I run it because of following error. When I run it individually using "fit" it passes every time I run it. Any suggestions?

Error details :

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'src')
     at VgMediaDirective.ngOnDestroy (node_modules/@videogular/ngx-videogular/fesm2015/videogular-ngx-videogular-core.mjs:959:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is coming from `@videogular` npm package.

Do you have version 5.0.1 of `@videogular` installed?

If not, install that version to see if the error goes away.

If the error does not go away, I would mock the directive instead of providing the real one in the unit tests.

Check out mocking directives here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57099227/7365461

Comment: Yes I am already at this version 5.0.1. I am not sure whats wrong with test since if I run it individually, it succeeds. I am not clear why do I need to change my test?

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry I am not sure either

Comment: So basically looks like this is just failure being thrown when all tests are executed together. When this test case is executed as a single test, it passes.. phewww I have been spending 3 days dealing with these errors.